# Vim shows "Press ENTER or type command to continue” when start

Tags: vim, enter, vundle

VIM starts with a message "Press ENTER or type command to continue", it happens for VIM, but not GVIM, GVIM starts without showing "Press ENTER or type command to continue”.

The Vundle settings in my .vimrc file, OS is windows 7.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""Vundle start"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=C:/Users/penpan/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Avoid a name conflict with L9
Plugin 'user/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
"NERDTree
Plugin 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
"color scheme molokai
Plugin 'tomasr/molokai'
"Match Tag
Plugin 'Valloric/MatchTagAlways'
"ctags
Plugin 'szw/vim-tags'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""End Vundle"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

I comment this line:

```
call vundle#end()            " required
```

Then it is ok! VIM starts without showing press enter prompt. so I believe this call makes the prompt happening. I add silent! in front of it as below:

```
silent! call vundle#end()
```

but no use, VIM still show the prompt.
and add below in .vimrc:

```
set shortmess+=T
set cmdheight=2
```

does not work.

I tried to find answer in google, fine many suggestions, but none of them work :(

Vundle is a common plugin, has anyone have the same question with me?

Appreciate if you can help.

only if I remove below, the press enter prompt disappears:

```
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""End Vundle"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
colorscheme molokai "because molokai is installed by Vundle, so it only work after Vundle is lunched!
```

=================================fixed====================================
after I remove plugin MatchTagAlways in vundle config, issue fixed.below is the steps I find the issue:

1. firstly, you need to know what config area cause the issue, for me, it is the config of Vundle.
2. add :redraw! after call vundle#begin() and call vundle#end()
3. open vim, it will show the error message above the press enter message

before:

Press ENTER or type command to continue

after:

MatchTagAlways unavailable: requires python.

Press ENTER or type command to continue

4. now we get the root cause. fix it, or remove the plugin.

ps: gvim has +python3/dyn support, but vim haven't. so vim have the error if plugin MatchTagAlways installed.

Comment: Delete all of the plugins. Don't copy configs when you don't know what they do.

Comment: Thanks, i will remove the plugins which just copied from Vundle git home page. I even do not know what they are:)

Answer (score 3):

`set shortmess=a` in your `.vimrc` should stop that.

This wiki appears to be the authority on the issue:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts

Comment: I had to add `F` before it worked for me.

`set shortmess=aF`

Answer (score 0):

I dislike seeing "Press ENTER or type command to continue" when starting, especially when there's only one output line like "make finished." To resolve this, I clear the screen using `redraw` in Vim:

```
:silent make %< | redraw! | echo 'make finished'
```